# How to integrate amazon chime with reactjs?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, npm, aws-chime-sdk

I am using amazon IVS service with amazon chime. I am facing difficulty while integrating chime with our application.
What step I follow to integrate it ? Could you please help me how to get chime API URL and my service region is 'us-east-1'.
Chime Audio, Video and other chime functionality based on join chime API response data.
I have install NPM package "amazon-chime-sdk-js".

I referred this NPM URL
https://www.npmjs.com/package/amazon-chime-sdk-js